# Will linking external JS from Node.js via Apache allow me to use SSE "bypassing" the Apache proxy?

Tags: php, node.js, apache, reverse-proxy, server-sent-events

I want to serve (mostly) static content with Apache as that's what I'm comfortable in, but I want Node.js to handle server sent events. However, they are both on the same machine.

The problem is, if I set up my sseListener.html in my *Apache* server like so:

**sseListener.html (Apache)**

```
<body>
    <div id="test"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var source = new EventSource("http://localhost:8888/test2js.js");
        var test = document.getElementById("test");

        source.addEventListener("message", function(e){
            test.innerHTML = "";
            test.innerHTML = JSON.parse(e.data).test;
        }, false);

        source.onopen = function(){
            console.log("open: ");
        }

        source.onclose = function(){
            console.log("close: ");
        }

        source.onerror = function(){
            console.log("error: ");
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

I get this error in the console:

```
EventSource cannot load http://localhost:8888/test2js.js. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

The following is my Node server which the above script is trying to communicate with:

**test2js.js (Node)**

```
var http = require("http");
var date = new Date();

  function onRequest(request, response) {
    console.log("Request received.");
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/event-stream"});
    response.write("{ \"id\": \"" + date + "\", \"data\": \"test\"}");
    response.end();
  }

  http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
  console.log("Server has started.");
```

I realize this is because I'm trying to use an `EventSource` client served via Apache to communicate with a server hosted by Node, just like how an Ajax call would fail due to cross-domain issues.

Reading around the internet, I know I can just set up a proxy from Apache to Node, but then I've also read that this defeats my purpose of having Node handle concurrent connections - Apache will set up threads for its communication with Node instead of not having to do that at all.

How I understand this process to work:

[image]

But, I don't like that the requests have to route to Apache first then go to Node second. I want the requests to go straight to Node.

I realize there are two "obvious" ways to do this:

1. Set up my whole app in Node -> This is not a good option for me as I am much more comfortable with PHP and my JavaScript ability is not as good as my PHP
2. Just handle the SSE by Apache -> I'd rather not do this either. The server I'm running on isn't actually mine alone, I'm only mounting my app on it and "borrowing" the space so I'd like to implement something as lightweight as I can muster.

So thinking about the problem, I came up with a solution I'm not sure will work, but I don't know how to implement it either: make Apache fetch the client js code and link it to sseListener.html, like so:

```
<body>
    <div id="test"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/node/file/system/sseClient.js"></script>
</body>
```

The way I'm *guessing* this would work, then, would be like:
[image]

In other words: save the client.js file (with EventSource) in the Node directory, grab that file with Apache and attach it somehow, serve that to the client. So when the client makes a request, it will go straight to Node rather than Apache.

So my questions:

1. Is this possible?
2. If so, how can I implement this?
3. Otherwise, are there any other methods to serve files to clients by Apache but offset the SSE side to Node, *without* making it so that Apache has to also handle the connections?

Literally, all I want my Node server to do is push data to clients that Apache will generate. It won't do anything complex at all. I just want to use its ability for concurrent connections to make a more efficient app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think proxy is bad idea for your aims. Try this:

```
    var source = new EventSource("http://localhost:8888/test2js.js");
    var test = document.getElementById("test");

    source.onmessage = function(e){
        test.innerHTML = "";
        var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        test.innerHTML = data.test + data.date;
    };
```

In your test2js.js :

```
  function onRequest(request, response) {
  console.log("Request received.");
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/event-stream",
                           "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
                     });
  response.write("data:{\"date\":"+date+",\"test\":\"some value\"}\n\n");
  response.end();
  }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. But when I tried your code, it still gave me the same error: `EventSource cannot load http://localhost:8888/test2js.js. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: Erm, no, sorry, I'm not seeing that error anymore. I'm seeing "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token M" which I can handle. I was actually starting up a different, wrong server. Thanks!